# Import Duty on electronics being brought to India from the USA

Tags: customs-and-immigration, india, electronic-items, import-taxes

hey my friend is coming back from usa to india,he is carrying used 2 laptops and 4 used mobiles.and my iphone 6s plus 128gb is among them.will it lead to any problem.am ready to pay import duty,wat will be the import duty on my item which cost aprrox 80000INR

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to avoid import taxes is to have a company document and an invoice clearly proving that those parts had been bought long time ago. With 2 laptops and 4 phones, he might get questioned on why he is using so many parts for his own needs. If he can't prove that those aren't new parts and that he was owning those before the trip, then there might be some taxes applied.

Comment: Does this apply to Indian law specifically? Also, if they are being imported (ie will remain long term, as opposed to leaving again with the traveller within the next month or so), most countries technically (if not often in practice) apply import duty on used items as well as new - admittedly adjusted to current value.

Comment: I don't think so. This is a general statement based on my own travel experience with electronic devices. Having an invoice dated in the past together with a company statement always helped me going through without paying taxes.